# how to join three tables and show the items based on timestamps in django

Tags: python, django

Friends, I am working on a site that shows a registered user his/her customized news feed based on the users they follow. What I want is that they should see the items from three models Question, Answer and Document, based on these items' timestamps.All my models have a timestamps field. How can I implement it?

Here is my views.py

```
def index(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    answers = Answer.objects.all()
    docs = Document.objects.all()

    return render(request,"welcome/index.html",locals())
```

I've kept my views.py simple over here. I just want to get an idea on how to manipulate all three models at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `chain` the objects, and sort using the common `timestamp` field of your models:

```
from itertools import chain

def index(request):
    items = sorted(chain(Question.objects.all(),
                         Answer.objects.all(),
                         Document.objects.all()), key=lambda obj: obj.timestamp)
    return render(request, "welcome/index.html", {'items': items})
```

Comment: thanks Moses, but one more question, can I do it something like '-obj.timestamps' so as to arrange them according to latest items?

Comment: but the order isn't according to latest items. it is kind of random.

Comment: @amankarn In that case, add `reverse=True` to the parameters in `sorted`

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have a field called `created_at` in all the models.

**Step 1: Merge all 3 lists.**

```
merged_list = []
merged_list.extend(questions)
merged_list.extend(answers)
merged_list.extend(docs)
```

**Step 2: Sort by the common field.**

```
merged_list.sort(key=lambda item: item.created_at)
```

(or) you can use something like this without `lambda`

```
from operator import attrgetter
sorted_list = sorted(merged_list, key=attrgetter('created_at'))
```